# Can I add a link to a second sharepoint site that redirects the reader back to a document located on another sharepoint location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have two sharepoint locations- I want to add a link to the second sharepoint site for a document I have uploaded to the 1st sharepoint site.  Is there a way to add a link to the 2nd sharepoint site which will redirect the reader back to the document on the 1st sharepoint?  I hate the idea of having to maintain the same document on two different sharepoint sites.

Answer (score 1):

In your document library on site 2, enable the management of content types in the document library settings. Then, add the Link to a document content type to the available content types. Create a new item in your document library using this content type and point it to the location in site 1.